# how to encrypt a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, passwords, cryptojs

I tried encrypting a string using javascript, and it worked very well.
But 1 day after it worked it stopped working, and i dont understand why.
Here's my code:

```js
alert(encrypt("hi", "123"));

function encrypt(data, key) {
  return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key).toString();
}

function decrypt(data, key) {
  return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

I tried running

```
alert(encrypt("hi", "123"));
```

to test if it worked, but no alert showed up.
Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You imported the aes package of `CryptoJs` and therefore the reference to CryptoJs does not exists.

Try to replace the import by `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>`

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/cnsvgxp9/1/)

Comment: it still doesn't work, but thanks for reacting!

Comment: That randomly worked, after 2 tries! thanks so much!